# Changing model field values through the view

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='post')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notify_type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notify:user_notifications')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

It records a user's action in regards to another user's post so that the owner of the post can be notified.

I then have this view:

```
class NotifyMarkRead(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserNotification,pk=pk)
        if obj.read != True:
            obj.read == True
        else:
            obj.read == False
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

This is the view that handles the user clicking on the notification. This view is supposed to check if `read` is equal to True or False (it is false by default). If the user clicks on the notification the view is supposed to update `read` to True. However, it isn't doing that. So how do I update the `read` field in my model when a user goes through this view?

Also I'm no that the page is being accessed however it just goes to `/notify/1/read/` instead redirecting back to `/notify/`. Just sure if that's important here.

Here are my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from notify import views

app_name = 'notify'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UserNotifications.as_view(),name='user_notifications'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/read/$',views.NotifyMarkRead.as_view(),name='user_notify_toggle'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.save()`

try this to save your updates

Comment: you are also using == for assignment. that's not correct, use single = Instead of `obj.read == True`  use `obj.read = True`